# how to swap update value of single column

Tags: oracle

```
id   sal 
101  5000
102  9000
```

i want update sal column like

```
id   sal 
101  9000
102  5000
```

Comment: It makes no sense. Please be more specific.

Comment: Just: `update table_name set id = sal, sal=id;`

Comment: What do you need to do - switch the two salaries between two id's? What if the table has 30,000 id's, which ones do you want to switch? Is the assignment "I give you two id's, I want you to switch the salaries between those two"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the assignment is "from a table with two columns, id and sal, and 30,000 rows, write a query that swaps the salaries between id = 101 and id = 102", something like this should work:

```
update zz set sal = case id when 101 then (select sal from zz where id = 102)
                            when 102 then (select sal from zz where id = 101)
                            end
where id in (101, 102);
```

**Edit**: As demonstrated by Mottor in his Answer to this question, the statement can be written more concisely, as below. (Note that I prefer to use a CASE expression over DECODE - I think it's easier to read and maintain.)

```
update zz x set sal = (select sal from zz where id = case x.id when 101 then 102 
                                                               when 102 then 101 end)
where id in (101, 102);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE emp x
   SET sal =
          (SELECT sal
             FROM emp
            WHERE id = DECODE (x.id, :id1, :id2, :id1) )
 WHERE id IN ( :id1, :id2)
```